# Grails run-app 'Application metadata not found'

Tags: grails

I downloaded a serverpush example called GrailsChat and trying to run is on grails 2.4.4.

I had some issues with dependencies missing that took me a while to figure out (don't think it's related but just mentioning it).

When I run grails run-app I get:

```
 | Application metadata not found, please run: grails upgrade
```

When I run grails upgrade I get

```
 | Script 'Upgrade' not found, did you mean:
1) MigrateDocs
2) IntegrateWith
3) SetGrailsVersion
4) InstallDependency
5) DependencyReport

> Please make a selection or enter Q to quit:
```

I figure the issue is probably to do with the grails version I have being newer than the grails version that the sample app was targetting but I don't want to move back version simply to run an example (I'd rather understand the underlying issue).

Can anyone point me to some documentation that will help me understand what the application metadata is and how to move forward please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grails Upgrade command](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.4/guide/upgradingFrom23.html) is removed in 2.4. You might have to upgrade the app manually following the guide.

Or you can just run the service wrapper which will download the grails version automatically base on the app.

`./grailsw run-app`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have missed any one of mentioned

1. Not set grails proper Version
2. Missing application.properties file (with proper grails version)